スタートアップ支援プログラムのGWS環境でAPIを利用すると404エラーが発生する
スタートアップ支援プログラムのGWS環境において、以下事象が発生しております。
①適切な権限を付与しているが、APIでGET　https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customers/my_customer を実行すると404エラーが発生する。
②my_customerではなく、管理コンソールから参照できる顧客IDを指定すると403エラーが返ってくる。
GWSの契約によって利用できるAPIに差分があるのでしょうか？
